# What does git branch -M main do when you're on the wrong branch?

Tags: git

I accidently ran the `git branch -M main` command when I was **not** on the **master** branch.  **NOTE: The command was intented to rename the `master` branch to `main`. [See more](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-GitHub-renamed-its-master-branch-to-main).**  *While lots of articles explain how rename master to main, none explain how to recover from running this if you are on the wrong branch when you run it.*

### What happened

The following steps summarize the steps that happened:

```
git checkout feature/do-it
git branch -M main
git checkout main
Already on 'main'

# How do I fix this?
```

**Details on how it happened**

This happened because I blindly followed a command on github.com that shows how to rename your master branch to main when creating a new repository.  My `github/me/my-repo` webpage shows these commands to setup the new repo.

```
echo "# my-repo" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:me/my-repo.git
git push -u origin main
```

But when I ran `git branch -M main` I failed to realize that I was not on the **master** branch.  I was on the `feature/do-it` branch which was now gone!  And now I have both **master** and **main** branches!

### Searching for answers:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+git+branch+-M+main+do%3F - did not give me any useful results.
- Git book - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branch-Management didn't show what -M option does.  It does show

**Changing the master branch name**

```
$ git branch --move master main
```

Which is likely what -M does.  I'm just not sure.

### So my questions are:

**What does the command `git branch -M main` do, when your on a non-master branch**

**How do I recover?  Get the `master` branch renamed to `main` and get my `feature/do-it` branch back.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the command `git branch -M main` do, when your on a non-master branch

Things to know:

- There is no such thing as a "non-master branch". There are just branches, which themselves are just names. No name is "special" in any way.
- The command `git branch -M newname` is very simple: it changes the name of the *current* branch to `newname`. It doesn't know or care about anything else; it just does what you said to do.

So, if you were on branch `feature/do-it` at the time you said `git branch -M main`, then the branch `feature/do-it` was renamed to `main` — because that is what you said to do.

There is *also* (as you have discovered) a fuller form, `git branch -M oldname newname`. You can give that command while you are on *any* branch, and the result will be the same regardless, because you are specifying both names. But you *didn't* do that; you used a form where you supply only *one* name, which is taken as the new name, and the branch you are currently on is the one whose name is changed.

Then, too, there is your somewhat unhappy choice of `-M`. This is a "force" command: it will happily permit you to change a branch's name to a name currently held by some other branch. That's a slightly nutty thing to do if you don't really mean it; better to say `-m` instead, because Git will then stop you if you try to do that.

The good news, ultimately, is that, as I already said, branches are nothing but names. So it is trivial (and harmless) to rearrange or otherwise manipulate those names however you like. Just say what you really mean when you give the command, that's all.

(Also I should mention that everything you've done is undoable, because that's what Git is all about. You can find any previous state of affairs by saying `git reflog --all`. There, you will *see* the record of the renames, so you will understand exactly what you did — and exactly how to undo it.)

---

One final comment: I notice that in your search for answers you neglected to look at the actual docs. All of this is completely spelled out there. The docs for `git branch` are at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch. There you will see, for example, that `-m` is `--move`, and `-M` is `--move --force`.

I recommend (1) that you get very familiar with where the docs are, and (2) that you look at them *before* you go thrashing around with Git. Git is not a user-friendly notation; on the contrary, it makes it very easy for you to shoot yourself in the foot. Renaming branches is a benign exercise, and not a way that you can readily shoot yourself in the foot, but there are lots of commands that can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Good points.  Bookmarks made, and I changed my question to better explain what I meant by **non-master**.

Comment: Well, I think I've answered the question sufficiently. If you've changed the branch names incorrectly, just change them back again (and now you know how).

Comment: Yeah, I really messed things up by naming `feature/do-it` to `main` and then `master` to `main` so I basically lost my `feature/do-it` branch (because all references were now changed to `main`.  Luckily, based on git logs I could figure out how to repoint the branches to the right commits.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, `-M` is `--move --force` so it really lets you do some inadvisable things. But the `reflog` lets you find the SHA of the lost branch, so it wasn't really lost at all. :)